# Print out pointer value

Tags: c++, pointers, mfc

I am doing a threading, but i don't know how to print out the pointer value.

```
UINT __cdecl CThreadDlg::func(LPVOID pParam)
{
    data *ptr = (data*)pParam;
    AfxMessageBox(L"You have entered a thread function.");
    ptr->a = "abc12345";       // char * a
    AfxMessageBox(???);        // what should i put here to print out the value of a?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
CString a;
a.Format(_T("%p"), ptr->a);
AfxMessageBox(a);
```

Edit:
 to get value 'ptr->a' points to:

```
a.Format(_T("%s), ptr->a);
```

Comment: it works, but the characters has changed into Chinese font. how do i fix this?

Comment: anyway, i dont want to print out pointer address value, i just wanted to print out abc12345 instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
ptr->a
```

But that completely depends on the AfxMessageBox API.

Edit: Looks like AfxMessageBox expects a LPCTSTR which is nothing but a const char *.

```
LPCTSTR lpStr = (LPCTSTR)ptr->a;
```

This should help if your compiler isn't casting automatically

Comment: I truly hope his compiler *isn't* casting automatically, and I very much doubt this is what is wanted.

Comment: It works, but message box displaying ancient Chinese characters. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [swprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf(VS.71).aspx) function to build a C string with the text, then print that. Consider this example:

```
UINT __cdecl CThreadDlg::func(LPVOID pParam)
{
    data *ptr = (data*)pParam;
    AfxMessageBox(L"You have entered a thread function.");

    ptr->a = "abc12345";       // char * a

    wchar_t buf[ 1024 ];
    swprintf( buf, "ptr->a points to %p", ptr->a );
    AfxMessageBox(buf);        

    return 0;
}
```